# How can I implement a "default iterator" for a trait?

Tags: iterator, rust

I am trying to implement a default iterator for structs implementing a trait. My trait is called `DataRow`, represents a row of table cells, and looks like this:

```
pub trait DataRow<'a> {
    // Gets a cell by index
    fn getCell(&self, i: usize) -> &DataCell<'a>;

    // Gets the number of cells in the row
    fn getNumCells(&self) -> usize;
}
```

The default iterator I want to provide should use those two methods to iterate over the row and return cell references. In Java this would boil down to an abstract class `DataRow` that implements `Iterable`. In Rust I tried first with `IntoIterator`:

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a T
where
    T: DataRow<'a>,
{
    type Item = &'a DataCell<'a>;
    type IntoIter = DataRowIterator<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> DataRowIterator<'a, T> {
        return DataRowIterator::new(self);
    }
}
```

This does not work as anyone could implement their own iterator for their own implementation of the `DataRow` trait.

My second try was adding an `iter` method to the trait which creates the iterator and returns it:

```
fn iter(&self) -> DataRowIterator<'a, Self> {
    return DataRowIterator::new(self);
}
```

This does not work either, because the size of `Self` is not known at compile time. Since `DataRow` can contain an arbitrary number of cells, I also cannot mark it as `Sized` to get around that.

[My demo code including notes on the occurring errors](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc128a133ffb5d7471d47d130520936d&version=stable)

How would someone implement such a "default iterator" for a custom trait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `IntoIterator` for a trait object reference.

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a DataRow<'a> {
    type Item = &'a DataCell<'a>;
    type IntoIter = DataRowIterator<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> DataRowIterator<'a> {
        DataRowIterator::new(self)
    }
}
```

`DataRowIterator` should be modified to keep the trait object reference `&DataRow` instead of `&T` and use the methods available for the `DataRow` trait.

Comment: That worked, thank you! A quick follow up question, if you don't mind:
In the loop that is commented out in the code, I now have to write `for ref cell in (&row as &DataRow)`. Is there a way around this cast?

Comment: Some kind of cast is required, because as you said "anyone could implement their own iterator for their own implementation of the DataRow trait". You can create helper function `fn def_iter<T: DataRow>(p: &T) -> &DataRow { p }`, then the code will be `for cell in def_iter(&row)`. BTW, you don't need `ref`, cell is a reference already.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!